# XSD choice tag (mandatory fields)

Tags: xml, xsd

From the below choice elements the R01 and R99 should occur only once and mandatory fields . i tired with all possibilities  but no use ..

Please help me in making the below 01 an 99 record are mandatory and should occur only once in the file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://TargetNamespace.com/fileService"
            targetNamespace="http://TargetNamespace.com/fileService"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"

            nxsd:version="NXSD"
            nxsd:stream="chars"
            nxsd:encoding="US-ASCII"
>


  <xsd:element name="Root-Element">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" nxsd:choiceCondition="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|">
        <xsd:element name="R01" type="tns:R01" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:conditionValue="01"  />
        <xsd:element name="R22" type="tns:R22" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:conditionValue="22"  />
        <xsd:element name="R45" type="tns:R45" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:conditionValue="45"  />
        <xsd:element name="R99" type="tns:R99" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:conditionValue="99"  />
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="R01">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="name1" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
   <xsd:element name="name2" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="R22">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="name1"  type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
   <xsd:element name="name2" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="R45">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="name1"  type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
   <xsd:element name="name2" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
   <xsd:element name="name3" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="R99" >
 <xsd:sequence >
<xsd:element name="name1" type="xsd:string"  nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Your schema clearly says that the Root-Element can contain any number of R01, R22, R45, and R49 elements in any order. That's apparently not what you want, but your posting doesn't make at all clear what you DO want.

Comment: My paload contains  a record of 01 and 99 and these fields are mandatory , while the other two occurs 0-n number of times  . If i give  more than one 99/01 record it should not accept

Comment: What are the constraints on ordering of the R01, R22, R45, and R49 elements?